# Passing values to flash file issue

Tags: flash, url, flashvars

I have a question regarding the flashvar parameter in my flash.

I have a flash file like the following:

```
    <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://test.swf" width="640" 
height="480" PlayerVersion=11  allowScriptAccess="always" allowNetworking="all" 
wmode="transparent" basename="http://project/test" 
flashvars="path=/imagesFolder/&images=image1.png,image2.png,image3.png"/>
```

The flash rendered the the images based from the `flashvars` `path` and `image` file name.

However, the codes are from previous developer and I am not sure how the `images` and `path` got rendered in flash file. Are `path` and `image` are default variables for flash? I have googled it but all I got is how to pass value to flash, not explaining how it works. I need some helps here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can name your variables that a passed as flashvars as you want. In your case it is "path" and "images". I think those names are referenced somewhere in your code, and you can retrieve their values there.

More information about flashvars can be found [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html)